# Java API for Lucidworks fusion

Tags: lucidworks

I could not find the java API for Lucidworks fusion, when searched the internet. Is there one or only REST API's are supported in lucidworks fusion?

Answer (score 1):

There are Java APIs which are available for writing [plugins](https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion/2.0/Indexing_Data/Writing-a-Connector-Plugin-using-the-Lucidworks-Connector-Java-API.html). But REST APIs from Lucidworks Fusion can be leveraged and can be used not only in Java, but in any language. That's the benefit of having REST APIs, right? Please go through the [documentation](https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion/2.1/index.html) of Fusion 2.1 for all the REST APIs.